Why algorithm free-object(x) involves manipulation of free list F?
It is often desirable to keep all elements of a doubly linked list compact in storage, using, for example, the first  index locations in the multiple-array representation. (This is the case in a paged, virtual-memory computing environment.) Explain how to implement the proceduresALLOCATE-OBJECT  and FREE-OBJECT so that the representation is compact. Assume that there are no pointers to elements of the linked list outside the list itself. (Hint: Use the array implementation of a stack.)
FREE-OBJECT(x)
p = F.top - 1
p.prev.next = x
p.next.prev = x
x.key = p.key
x.prev = p.prev
x.next = p.next
PUSH(F, p)

The question ask for implementing an array based stack.
However the hint doesn't seem resonating with provided solution.
I guess one should free the element and shift accordingly to maintain compact doubly linked-list.
It would be helpful if someone can figure out working of proposed solution.
